# Check if XML node exists in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlnode

Is there a better way of finding if XML node exists (in XSLT) rather than using:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="...........">body node exists</xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>body node missing</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Alternatives to `xsl:choose`

Define *better*; `xsl:choose` covers conditional expression quite well.  Being *better* requires measurement against some criteria, and none were provided.  Nevertheless, here are some alternatives which you can assess as you see fit:

### XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:if test="/path/to/node">node exists</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(/path/to/node)">node missing</xsl:if>
```

### XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (/path/to/node) then 'node exists' else 'node missing'"/>
```